# How to append dictionaries in lists the right way

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given the following CSV file, I am trying to get dictionaries in a list using a for loop and the `append` function:

```
Margherita , 5.5
Salami , 7.0
Schinken , 7.0
```

My code is:

```
Pizzadict = {}
Pizzalist = []
with open("preisliste.txt", 'r') as textfile:
    preisenlist_csv = csv.reader(textfile)
    for ind, rows in enumerate(preisenlist_csv):
        Pizzadict.clear()
        Pizzadict[rows[0]] = rows[1]
        Pizzalist.append(Pizzadict)
print(Pizzalist)
```

Output:

```
[{'Schinken ': ' 7.0'}, {'Schinken ': ' 7.0'}, {'Schinken ': ' 7.0'}]
```

So why does the list take only the last dictionary and print it 3 times ?
I wanted to get a list like

```
[1.dict, 2. dict, 3.dict]
```

and not

```
[3.dict, 3.dict, 3.dict]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Pizzalist.append(Pizzadict)` appends *references to the same dictionary object*.

When you mutate it with `Pizzadict[rows[0]] = rows[1]`, for example, or `Pizzadict.clear()`, that change is reflected by the three references.

You need to append a *copy* of the dictionary:

```
Pizzalist.append(Pizzadict.copy())
```

Or simply build a new dict each time:

```
Pizzalist.append({rows[0]: rows[1]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this :

```
with open('preisliste.txt') as textfile:
    PizzaList = [i.strip().split(',') for i in textfile.readlines()]
PizzaDict = [{i:j} for i,j in PizzaList]
```

**Output** :

```
[{'Margherita ': ' 5.5'}, {'Salami ': ' 7.0'}, {'Schinken ': ' 7.0'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you append the same dictionary 3 times, dictionaries are reference types, so your list stores a reference to the dictionary 3 times, not individual dictionaries, instead, just create new dictionaries in the for loop.

```
for ind, rows in enumerate(preisenlist_csv):
    Pizzalist.append({rows[0]: rows[1]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l= list()
dic = {}
dic['1'] = 1
print(dic)
l.append(dic)
print(l)
dic.clear()
print(l)
dic['2'] = 2
l.append(dic)
print(l)
```

You get:

```
{'1': 1}
[{'1': 1}]
[{}]
[{'2': 2}, {'2': 2}]
```

You see, `l.append(dic)` actually synchronizes with dic when you use dic.clear().

In your case you dont have to clear the dic everytime, just refine a new dic or simply `append({rows[0]:rows[1]})`